# Named Forced Include File alternative doxygen

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include, doxygen

we are trying to get Doxygen running on a large C++ code base,
though we have noticed that we have an enormous list of warnings of which we currently don't know if they are wrongly documented or mistakes in the configuration or doxygen-parsing.

During some analysis of this, we noticed that our build system uses something called 'Named Forced Include File' (e.g. The [/FI option of MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx))

This file contains some important defines, which are simply includes in every header and c++ file of our code base, though we can't find out where in the configuration we could tell doxygen about this file.

tnx in advance

JVApen